# What should a unit test for a tostring method look like?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods, tostring

I am in search of help in writing a unitTest for a toString method. I have my property and constructor unit test going good, but we didn't learn about a unit test for a method.  Can anyone help? If more context is needed, please let me know.  The method to be tested is below:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}; is a {1} with a resolution of {2} and uses a {3} for media storage",
            base.ToString(), this.Type, this.MegaPixels, this.MediaStorage);
    }
```

And the base.toString():

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}; {2}, {3}, {4}; {5} MSRP: {6} Cost: {7}",
            this.Type, this.PartNumber, this.Brand, this.Series, this.Model,
            this.Description, this.MSRP, this.Cost);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your unit test should

1. create an instance of the class you're testing;
2. invoke its `ToString()`;
3. check that the resulting string is what you'd expect.

You ought to do this for a couple of "normal" cases, but also test some corner cases: nulls, empty lists, partially filled in instances, model names with quotation marks or `{}` in, and the like.

Comment: How do I invoke the tostring method in this scenario? And should the instance of the class have all of the above properties?

Comment: @Shades9323 You invoke it by creating an instance in your test code, and then invoking it just as you'd invoke any method of any object. You want to test various scenarios, so make sure you have at least one that has all its properties set, but also some that have bits missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
using NUnit.Framework;

public class UserTests
{
    [Test]
    public void RepresentsItselfAsString()
    {
        var name = "John";
        var john = new User(name);
        Assert.AreEqual(name, $"{john}");
    }
}

class User
{
    readonly string name;

    public User(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{name}";
    }
}
```

**NB**! String interpolation in the expected value is required in order to avoid false positive when implementation has no `override` keyword.