# Unit testing toString method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I try to unit tes a Tostring method:

So I have this code:

```
public class Parcel
{
 //Working
}
```

Comment: `ToString` does **return** a string, which you have to check against your expected result.

Comment: `var parse; = new Parsel { Name = "Hello", ... };`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should a unit test for a tostring method look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508334/what-should-a-unit-test-for-a-tostring-method-look-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your test like this:

```cs
[Test]
public void ParcelsUpToWeightOneKGShouldBeDepartmentMail()
{
    var parcel = new Parcel { Name="pacel ", PostalCode="2582Cd", Weight= 0.02m, Value=0.0m};          
         
    Assert.Equal("Name: pacel - Postal code 2582Cd - Weight 0.02 - Value 0.0 - Department Mail", parcel.ToString());
}
```

The `ToString()` method *returns* a string, but does not change the state of parcel. So you should check the returned value.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But that is the error I get. If I do it like this, then I will get this error:Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'type'; use an 'suffix' suffix to create a literal of this type

Comment: Ok, just edited my answer. Your should post the full error messages in your question.

Comment: Oke, thank you. I only get this error: String lengths are both 78. Strings differ at index 6.
      Expected: "Name:  parcel - Postal code 2582Cd - Weight 0.02 - Value 0.0 ..."
      But was:  "Name: parcel  - Postal code 2582Cd - Weight 0,02 - Value 0,0 ..."
      -----------------^
    

  Stack Trace: 
    Tests.ParcelsUpToWeightOneKGShouldBeDepartmentMail() line 26

Comment: Ok, now you have to compare the 'Expected' and 'But was' strings and find the difference. Then decide which one is correct and adjust either the test or the `ToString()` method. I won't do this for you. But in your error message the character position (0-based) is mentioned. And I did see that Expected is with ',' and But was is with '.'.

Answer (score 1):

You write: "And I just want to unit test the first criteria of the method CreateDepartmentValue." In that case, don't test the `ToString()` method, but test the value of your `Department` property. Your test becomes more stable, because otherwise if you change your `ToString()` method, you will have to change your test, although you are only interested in the value of your `Deptartment` property.

Your test might look like this:

```
[Test, Pairwise]
public void DepartementShouldDependOnWeight(
       [Values(1.0m, 1.01m, 10.0m, 10.01m)]decimal weight,
       [Values("Mail","Regular","Regular","Heavy")]string expectedDepartment)
{
    var parcel = new Parcel { Weight = weight, Value = 0 };
    Assert.AreEqual(parcel.Department, expectedDepartment);
}
```